# Uniform and absolute convergence of $\sum \frac{2^n}{n^2+1} x^{2n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, uniform-convergence

Find the radius of converence of the series

$$\sum \frac{2^n}{n^2+1} x^{2n}$$

and analyze the absolute and/or uniform convergence

**My attempt**

1. The convergence radius of this serie is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} ( x^{2n}=(x^2)^n)$
2. If $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},$ the series converges, since it is the sequence $\sum\frac{1}{n^2+1}$
3. If $x=\frac{-1}{n}$ also converges, applying the Dirichet criteria for alternating series

My doubt is when we talk about the uniform convergence:

Since the serie $\sum \frac{2^n}{n^2+1} (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})^{2n}$ converges and

$$||{f_n}||_{\infty} = \frac{1}{n^2+1}$$

by the M-test the series must converges uniformly on $[-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}], $ correct?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Only quibble is at the negative endpoint,  it's actually not alternating there since the value is being raised to an even power.  But it still converges there, by the same logic as in your #2.

Comment: Indeed, thanks!